# Как лучше, надежнее организовать алгоритм действий?

Tags: python

Есть скрипт на Python мне нужно чтоб он в фоне висел и в заданное время, допустим каждый час, выполнялся. Через `time.sleep()` говорят не очень хорошая идея.

Есть функция определяющая рабочее время или нет, на текущий момент и в зависимости
от возврата, `True` или `False` определяется необходимость дальнейшего выполнения скрипта.

```py
def is_working_hours(self) -> bool:
    if 0 <= date.today().weekday() < 5 and datetime.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") not in non_working_days and 10 <= datetime.now().hour < 23:
        return True
    print("\nСегодня выходной или праздничный день. Торги не проводятся.\n")
    return False
```

Comment: Основные минусы при длительных `time.sleep()` - вы на это время теряете контроль над программой, останавливается основной цикл, что для gui приложений приводит к зависанию интерфейса, вы можете во время сна выключить программу только аварийно и т.д.. Поэтому эффективней использовать таймеры, потоки, планировщики заданий. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/how-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds

Comment: @СергейКох, но sleep в потоке усыпит только поток, а ui продолжит работать. Или есть подвохи?

Comment: Не понял, прога консольная или нет? Если нет, то что там print делает?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я имел в виду однопоточный `gui`, такой как `tkinter`.

Comment: @СергейКох, вроде gui всегда однопоточный, но это ж не мешает другие потоки создавать?

Comment: @Qwertiy print так для отладки... а так да скрипт будет висеть в фоне, в телегу еще слать сообщения по событию.

Comment: @СергейКох Понял Вас, остановлюсь на APScheduler.